# Http Server not returning content-encoding header in response

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, http-accept-encoding

I'm making `http` request using `HttpWebRequest` client

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestString);
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
request.Method = "GET"; 
request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
```

```
public void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers["Content-Encoding"]);
            
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved)
    {   
        Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(inputStream);
        string responseString = stream.ReadToEnd(); 
    }
}
```

On `Apache` settings `gzip` compression is enabled and working normally because when making request to the same `url` from chrome browser I can see `content-encoding` in response Headers. Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

But when I make the same request using the above provided code `Content-Encoding` key exists in headers but it's value is empty string.

Why `content-encoding` value is missing in my response header?
Here is the response headers string

```
Headers = {Connection: keep-alive  Vary: Accept-Encoding  Content-Encoding:   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  Content-Length: 36954  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8  Date: Fri, 18 Sep 2020 11:31:25 GMT  Server: nginx/1.10.2  X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else meets the same problem.
In my case the prblem was in line

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

I've changed it to

```
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
```

It's strange to me, because my project .Net version is 4.7.1
However now it works normally.